# Unable to mask the input

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, maskedinput

This should be simple but for some reason I am not getting it right. :/

I am using the jQuery masked input plugin available [here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

The following is my code snippet:

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#newStudentForm").validate();
});
jQuery(function($){
   $("#Sphone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="Sphone" id="Sphone"  size="28px"/>
```

As of now, I cannot see any mask in the textbox. How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running? Could you provide more of your page's code?

Comment: This really looks like copy&paste from two different sources. or why else do you mix the two ways to register a domready event on the same page?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Well, right. The first piece is probably from jQuery Validate. The second piece is from the aforementioned input mask plugin. The answer below is probably the fix, but I think we need to see more of the page to see what else might be going wrong.

Comment: @rdesai I think you're going to have to supply a little more code, perhaps a link to the page, so we can help you debug the problem.

Comment: @magzalez

jQuery:
<script src="Jquery/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#newStudentForm").validate();
});
$(function() {
 $( "#rad1" ).buttonset();
});
jQuery(function($){
   $("#Sphone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
</script>

HTML:
 <td>Student's Phone Number : </td>
 <td><input type="text" maxlength="10" name="Sphone" id="Sphone"  size="28" class="required"/></td>

Comment: Was either answer helpful? If it was, you should accept an answer. If not, you should edit your question or comment again.

Answer (score 2):

**CHECK** that you include the plugin file

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="Sphone" id="Sphone"  size="28"/> // not `28px`


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#newStudentForm").validate();
  $("#Sphone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

Comment: I had tried this before, it doesnt work for some reason. Sorry.

Comment: I tried that, it still isnt working. Sorry. I would like to know why to replace 28px with 28.

Comment: @rdesai It defaults to pixels. It is best to style or "size" fields and any other elements in the CSS rather than in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I shall style the CSS but I am afraid the mask is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you gave me, I got it working at http://jsfiddle.net/Sgu6e/.

Here's what I did:

I removed the line `$("#rad1").buttonset();` as it did not apply to the code you gave me and was breaking the rest of the JS.

Then I changed the rest of the JS to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#newStudentForm").validate();
    $("#Sphone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

Again, you can see it working at http://jsfiddle.net/Sgu6e/.

Comment: I am glad its working for you. I tried it in my code but unfortunately, it is not working for some reason.

Comment: Here is my updated code (similar to yours):

<script src="Jquery/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#newStudentForm").validate();
  $("#Sphone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
//$(function() {
 //$( "#rad2" ).buttonset();  //later
 //$( "#radio" ).buttonset();  //later
//});
</script>

Comment: <td>Student's Phone Number : </td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength="10" name="Sphone" id="Sphone"  size="28" class="required"/></td>

I have included jQuery files. Its not working for me, its driving me crazy! Sorry.

Comment: You should try making a copy on http://jsfiddle.net. It'll be much more helpful than copying and pasting code into a comment.